# Python-Django ImportError at No module named urls

Tags: python, django

I have created Djnago project in digitalocean

. Unfortunately, i am facing issue when i run the project

ImportError at / No module named urls

http://www.btcdoller.com/

digitalocean

https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io

```
pip install django-registration-redux
```

file settings.py   add

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'registration', #should be immediately above 'django.contrib.admin'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # ...other installed applications...
)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # One-week activation window; you may, of course, use a different value.
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True # Automatically log the user in.
```

file urls.py add

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this, but did you put an init.py in the folder where there is urls.py ?

Comment: It's insecure to use runserver on a public site, or use `DEBUG=True` on a public site. You are using Django 1.8 which is end of life and does not receive security updates any more. The error message shows that you are using an import `from django.urls import path` (which requires Django 2.0), and `patterns(...)` (which has been deprecated since Django 1.8 in 2015). I suggest that you upgrade to at least Django 1.11 LTS, and make sure that you are following a tutorial/book that is written for the same version of Django as you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is `django-registration-redux` causing this error. The stack trace shows you are getting an error on the following line in your `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path
```

It may be that you have not configured your environment correctly on the digital ocean server that you are hosting on. Make sure you have done a `pip install` on all the requirements, including `pip install django`

Comment: my urls.py file :                                                                                 
 [ from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url ,patterns
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.urls import path 

urlpatterns =  patterns('', 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    path(r'^accounts', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

) ]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your ROOT_URLCONF in your settings.py file it has to be

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'yoursite.urls'
```

sorry but I cant write comments yet!